# MongoDB MongooseError: Cannot call `collection.aggregate()` before initial connection is complete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

[My website](https://www.horsebnb.dk/) built with [NextJS](https://nextjs.org/) (and hosted with Vercel) is using Mongoose in my NodeJS API to connect to my MongoDB database.

I get this weird error for only about 1% of the users:

```
MongooseError: Cannot call `hotels.aggregate()` before initial connection is complete if `bufferCommands = false`. Make sure you `await mongoose.connect()` if you have `bufferCommands = false`.
at NativeCollection.<computed> [as aggregate] (/var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:193:15)
at /var/task/node_modules/mongoose/lib/aggregate.js:998:18
at /var/task/node_modules/kareem/index.js:23:7
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

(`hotels` is the collection that is being displayed, and I'm calling the `.aggregate()` function on it in my API)

I can't reliably reproduce the error, but have had it happen to me too.

I'm following NextJS recommended way to connect to MonogoDB [from their example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose/lib/dbConnect.js):

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI

if (!MONGODB_URI) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

/**
 * Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
 * in development. This prevents connections growing exponentially
 * during API Route usage.
 */
let cached = global.mongoose

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

async function dbConnect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
    }

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      return mongoose
    })
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise
  return cached.conn
}

export default dbConnect
```

Contrary to the error message, I am awaiting the mongoose.connect(). My API starts like this:

```
import dbConnect from "utils/dbConnect";
import HotelModel from "models/HotelModel";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  await dbConnect();

      try {
        const pipeline = {}; // this is a big aggregation pipeline

        const hotels = await HotelModel.aggregate(pipeline);

        return res.status(200).json(hotels);
      } catch{
        ... 
      }
}
```

Does anyone have ideas to why this might happen?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove

```
const opts = {
      bufferCommands: false,
}
```

or set `bufferCommands: true` explicitly.

Vercel is running on AWS Lambda, and sometimes it causes problems with cached connections. One of the Vercel contributors complained about the corresponding PR in mongoose https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/9239#issuecomment-659000910

They recommended to avoid `bufferCommands: false` in the thread and removed it from the official mongoose recommendations a year later: [docs/lambda.md](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/commit/09dae52#diff-52d065f83ba13a7d08e51ff9afaf37390d669dc49483963dda0f992df2ffa70e)

Comment: Thank you! I have just pushed your answer to the production code. I'll keep an eye on my errors collection over the next 24-36 hours, and report back here with an update

Comment: Okay so there's been no new errors since I changed the bufferCommands:true, so thanks so much, this did fix it

Answer (score 0):

Add this to connection options:

```
 bufferMaxEntries:0
```

> bufferMaxEntries - The MongoDB driver also has its own buffering
> mechanism that kicks in when the driver is disconnected. Set this
> option to 0 and set bufferCommands to false on your schemas if you
> want your database operations to fail immediately when the driver is
> not connected, as opposed to waiting for reconnection.

[documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/connections.html)